# Make loop iterate through range but limited to input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to python so I apologize in advance if the question is too easy.

I'm trying to make a simulation to find the optimization point on a dataframe. This is what I have so far:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np

loops = int(input('Q of simulations: '))
cost = 175
sell_price = 250
sale_price = 250/2
# order = 1000
simulation = 0

profit = 0
rows = []

order = range(1000, 3000)
ordenes = []

for i in order:
    ordenes.append(i)

for i in ordenes:

    demand = math.trunc(1000 + random.random() * (2001))

    if demand >= i:
        profit = (sell_price - cost)* i
        rows.append([simulation, demand, i, profit, (demand - i)])
    else:
        profit = (sell_price - cost)* demand - (i - demand)* (sale_price - cost) 
        rows.append([simulation, demand, i, profit, (demand - i)])



DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = ['#Simulation', 'Demand', 'Order', 'Utility', 'Shortage'])
print(DataFrame)

DataFrame.loc[DataFrame['Utility'].idxmax()]
```

The current output (for any number specified in tis:

```
      #Simulation   Demand  Order   Utility  Shortage
0               0     2067   1000   75000.0      1067
1               0     1392   1001   75075.0       391
2               0     1042   1002   75150.0        40
3               0     1457   1003   75225.0       454
4               0     1930   1004   75300.0       926
...           ...      ...    ...       ...       ...
1995            0     1823   2995  195325.0     -1172
1996            0     2186   2996  204450.0      -810
1997            0     1384   2997  184450.0     -1613
1998            0     1795   2998  194775.0     -1203
1999            0     1611   2999  190225.0     -1388

[2000 rows x 5 columns]
#Simulation         0.0
Demand           2922.0
Order            2989.0
Utility        222500.0
Shortage          -67.0
Name: 1989, dtype: float64
```

Desired Output (writing 5 in the input):

```
      #Simulation   Demand  Order   Utility  Shortage
0               0     2067   1000   75000.0      1067
1               1     1392   1001   75075.0       391
2               2     1042   1002   75150.0        40
3               3     1457   1003   75225.0       454
4               4     1930   1004   75300.0       926


[5 rows x 5 columns]
#Simulation         4.0
Demand           1930.0
Order            1004.0
Utility         75300.0
Shortage          926.0
Name: 1989, dtype: float64
```

I really don't know how to make it happen, I've tried everything that comes to my mind but the outcome either fails on the 'order' column or as shown above.

Comment: You understand why you're getting 2000 rows, right?  Because of `order = range(1000,3000)`.  If you only want 5 rows, then do `order = range(1000,1000+loops)`.

Comment: :O
I guess that with more experience I'll get all the details. I feel kind of dumb now hahaha, but that made it, so Thanks a lot Tim!!!